# Build a cron expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, cron

I want to build a cron expression for following -
which should run every two weeks and start from specific day of month.

I tried to build expression like this -

5 4 2/14 * * * (Here i want to run cron at 04:05 on every 14th day-of-month from 2 through 31)

Can somebody help?

Comment: Your question is tagged with `ruby-on-rails` and `ruby` – do you want to build the crontab line(s) programmatically?

Comment: You can try https://crontab.guru/ for creating CRON expression.

Comment: @Stefan I am using cron2english gem to cron cron expression to human readable format. So that's why tagged it with ruby and ruby-on-rails.
And while parsing the cron expression it is giving me the invalid error.

Answer (score 2):

So, you want it to run on the 2nd, then 14 days later, and again 14 days later?
As this is not an enormous list, just give that list:

```
5 4 2,16,30 * *
```

Comment: this would also be more easy to understand for a human than a dynamic pattern.

Comment: The cron given it is incorrect, there's an extra asterisk. Even with the correct form, it will run 3 times a month. 5 4 2,16,30 * * . In this case it would be better to use  5 4 14,28 * * In that way wou will be sure to run twice in Feb too.

Comment: Cron should start from 2nd day of the month and then runs every time after 14 days.
What you have suggested will run only on 2nd, 16th and 30th of the month. And So in case of "February" it may not be able to achieve an objective.

Comment: If it is February, it simply can't run after 2 times 14 days. 
Or do you want the command to run a guaranteed 3 times every month?

Answer (score 0):

```
5 4 * * 1 test $(($(date +%W)%2)) -eq 1 && your_command
```

Ok, the tricky part to make it run every two weeks is to know what day of the week is the first 2nd. Let's imagine it is a Monday, this monday, and this week (number 13). We we'll focus on make it run every second monday.

`5 4 * * 1` Every monday script or command works at 04:05

`$(($(date +%W)%2))` Evaluates the numeric week expresion and gets his module (1 odd or 0 par)

`test $(($(date +%W)%2)) -eq 1` True if the week is odd, we avoid par weeks. We can change it to -eq 0 in case of need it to work on par weeks

`&& your_command` If the previous condition works, your script or command runs